# rake fails with "Virtual timer expired"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

The following is my environment:

- OS X 10.5
- Xcode 3.1.4
- rvm 0.1.38
- ruby 1.8.9-p399 (via rvm)
- rails 2.3.8

I started getting this error when rake tries to run my tests:

```
bash$ rake
Virtual timer expired
bash$  # End of output!
```

And with tracing enabled:

```
bash$ rake --trace
** Invoke default (first_time)
** Invoke test (first_time)
** Execute test
** Invoke test:units (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:load
Virtual timer expired
bash$
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing your system specs! Many posters forget to do that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like there is an problem in ruby, [rev23993 causes Virtual Timer Expired when forking](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/2103#note-2), which in turn triggers the error inside the **mysql** gem.

The practical workaround seems to be to *downgrade the mysql gem from 2.8.1*
to version 2.7:

```
#environment.rb
config.gem 'mysql', :version => '2.7'
```

Comment: As of 2011 Q1, I would recommend everybody to user Bundler (http://gembundler.com/) in preference of `config.gem`.